# Recording audio streaming app in mobile device using Jmeter not working

Tags: ios, performance, audio-streaming, jmeter-plugins, podcast

I have tried recording action of Native app(Xamarin based) used in iOS.Could any one provide any suggestion on how to record audio streaming/playing podcast through the app. Also after setting proxy for Jmeter, the audio content doesn't play as expected and not recorded in Jmeter.

I have tried different alternatives.
1.Disabling Firewall in the device
2.Fiddler to record the network traffic
3.Blazemeter to record some actions
4.Tried enabling airplane mode in the device

Could any one provide some alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

As it evidenced by its name [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) can only record [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) traffic, so audio streaming will be only recorded if it's encapsulated into HTTP packets.

For other protocols unfortunately you won't be able to record/replay streaming requests, you need to determine which [network protocol(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) are being used under the hood (you can use i.e. [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/ios/) for this) and once done you can replicate your iOS application outgoing network calls by using relevant Samplers or Plugins, i.e. [HLS Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/HLS-3.0-Release) or [WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers) or whatever plugin/library is appropriate